# Movimentação com TouchScrren 2D

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity-5

Preciso fazer um código de C#Script para a movimentação de um personagem 2d no Unity.

Desenvolvi um código que roda bem no pc usando as setas, porem não tenho ideia de como fazer para ele se mover usando o touchScren de um celular Android.

Segue o que já fiz:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
   {

public float velocidade;
public float forcaPulo;
private bool estaNoChao;
public Transform chaoVerificador;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Movimentacao();
}

void Movimentacao()
{

    estaNoChao = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, chaoVerificador.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Piso"));
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * velocidade * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * velocidade * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 180);
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script básico para facilitar o entendimento:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveTouch : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 1.5f;
    
    //Controle de Zoon
    private Vector2 v2_current_Distance;
    private Vector2 v2_previous_Distance;
    private float f_comfort_zone;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1;
    private GameObject go;
    
    //Controle de Rotaçao
    private Vector2 firstPressPos;
    private Vector2 secondPressPos;
    private Vector2 currentSwipe;
    
    void Start ()
    {
        go = GameObject.Find ("target");
    }
    
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 2 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Input.GetTouch (1).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            v2_current_Distance = Input.GetTouch (0).position - Input.GetTouch (1).position;
            v2_previous_Distance = ((Input.GetTouch (0).position - Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition) - (Input.GetTouch (1).position - Input.GetTouch (1).deltaPosition));
            
            //Funçao Zoon
            float touchDelta = v2_current_Distance.magnitude - v2_previous_Distance.magnitude;
            
            if (touchDelta <= 1) {
                mScaleFactor = transform.localScale.x;
                mScaleFactor *= 0.9f;
                transform.localScale = new Vector3 (mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            }
            
            if (touchDelta > 1) {
                mScaleFactor = transform.localScale.x;
                mScaleFactor *= 1.1f;
                transform.localScale = new Vector3 (mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            }  
        } else if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;
            go.transform.Translate (touchDeltaPosition.x * speed * Time.deltaTime, touchDeltaPosition.y * speed * Time.deltaTime, touchDeltaPosition.y * speed * Time.deltaTime); 
            
        } else if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) {
            Vector2 touch = Input.GetTouch (0).position;
            
            if (touch.y < Screen.height / 4) {
                Debug.Log ("Para Baixo");
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.right, 2);
            }  else if (touch.x < Screen.width / 2 && touch.y > Screen.height / 4 && touch.y < (Screen.height - (Screen.height / 4))) {
                Debug.Log ("Para Esquerda");
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, 2);
            }  else if (touch.y > Screen.height - (Screen.height / 4)) {
                Debug.Log ("Para cima");
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.left, 2);
            }  else {
                Debug.Log ("Para Direita");
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.down, 2);
            }            
        }        
    }
}
```

Anexando esse Script em qualquer `GameObject` você o controlara para todas as direções, detalhe, você precisa gerar o `APK`, pois, observe que não possui nenhum controle de mouse ou teclado!

Faça os teste, e é de fácil implementação da primeira parte da resposta que postei!

**Edit:**

Especificação de algumas funções usadas:

*Input.GetTouch(0).phase*, O `phase` é o estado em que se encontra o "toque" na tela, os estados básicos são:

> TouchPhase.Began = Detecta a posição de inicio do toque,
>
> TouchPhase.Moved = Informa para onde o touch moveu (em casos de arrastar),
>
> TouchPhase.Stationary = Informa onde o toque ficou estacionado, ou seja, esta segurando o toque na tela,
>
> TouchPhase.Ended = Informa o local exato de onde terminou o toque,
>
> TouchPhase.Canceled = Quando um toque é cancelado, somente em casos muito específicos.

*Input.GetTouch(0).position*, o `position` retorna a posição `x, y` e `z` de objetos ou localização do toque na tela.

*Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition*, O deltaPosition retorna um valor do tipo `Vector2` que representa a diferença da posição entre o toque atual e o toque anterior, e caso quizer saber o tempo entre os dois toques use:

```
deltaPosition.magnitude / Time.deltaTime
```

Segue [Documentação](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/) para maiores esclarecimentos!

Comment: Boa resposta. Mas, pra ganhar o meu +1, seria importante você adicionar a ela ao menos algumas explicações do funcionamento do código (porque por mais que o código seja reaproveitável, alguém com pouca experiência talvez tivesse grande dificuldade em entender seu funcionamento). Por exemplo, pode ao menos citar o que fazem certas funções como `Input.GetTouch (0).phase` ou `Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition`, entre outras.

Comment: @LuizVieira segue edição da resposta, muito bom saber que tens interesse por tal assunto! Prometo melhorar nesses detalhes!

Comment: Opa! Agora sim! +1 :)

Comment: @JúniorMoreira 
Obrigado :D o código funcionou, porem ele esta girando o personagem 2d ao invés de ir para os lados, eu gravei um vídeo para ver melhor como ficou 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZ3GoM8MUhY

Comment: @MatheusMuriel, troque o `transform.Rotate` por `transform.Position` se tiver duvidas e eu não estiver por aqui você pode consultar http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Eu tentei mudar para Transform.Position, porem ele acusou erro. e quando o erro saiu o personagem só pula.

Comment: Eu vou postar o codigo aqui nas respostas

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
private float speed = 1.5f;

//Controle de Zoon
private Vector2 v2_current_Distance;
private Vector2 v2_previous_Distance;
private float f_comfort_zone;
private float mScaleFactor = 1;
private GameObject go;

//Controle de Rotaçao
private Vector2 firstPressPos;
private Vector2 secondPressPos;
private Vector2 currentSwipe;

void Start()
{
    go = GameObject.Find("target");
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == 2 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Input.GetTouch(1).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        v2_current_Distance = Input.GetTouch(0).position - Input.GetTouch(1).position;
        v2_previous_Distance = ((Input.GetTouch(0).position - Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition) - (Input.GetTouch(1).position - Input.GetTouch(1).deltaPosition));

        //Funçao Zoon
        float touchDelta = v2_current_Distance.magnitude - v2_previous_Distance.magnitude;

        if (touchDelta <= 1)
        {
            mScaleFactor = transform.localScale.x;
            mScaleFactor *= 0.9f;
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        }

        if (touchDelta > 1)
        {
            mScaleFactor = transform.localScale.x;
            mScaleFactor *= 1.1f;
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        }
    }
    else if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
        go.transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed * Time.deltaTime, touchDeltaPosition.y * speed * Time.deltaTime, touchDeltaPosition.y * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    else if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
    {
        Vector2 touch = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

        if (touch.y < Screen.height / 4)
        {
            Debug.Log("Para Baixo");
            transform.position = new Vector3();
        }
        else if (touch.x < Screen.width / 2 && touch.y > Screen.height / 4 && touch.y < (Screen.height - (Screen.height / 4)))
        {
            Debug.Log("Para Esquerda");
            transform.position = new Vector3();
        }
        else if (touch.y > Screen.height - (Screen.height / 4))
        {
            Debug.Log("Para cima");
            transform.position = new Vector3();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Para Direita");
            transform.position= new Vector3();
        }
    }
}
```

}